# Finding average number of words and sentences in paragraph

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have text file from which I need to find the the **average number of words per sentence** and **the average number of sentences per paragraph** where a sentence is a sequence of words followed by either a full-stop, comma or exclamation mark, which in turn must be followed either by a quotation mark (so the sentence is the end of a quote or spoken utterance), or white space (space, tab or new-line character) and where a paragraph is any number of sentences followed by a blank line or by the end of the text without using regex.

I created a list of words i.e `[".", ",", "!", "\n", "\t", " "]` as my problem says and then iterated over the entire text file.

```
 with open("/Users/abhishekabhishek/downloads/l.txt") as f:
     text_lis = f.read()
# print(text_lis)
sentence_count = 0
ens_sentence = [".", ",", "!", "\n", "\t", " "]
for word in ens_sentence:
    if word in text_lis:
       sentence_count += 1
#print(sentence_count)
# sentence_count gave me the wrong output so I tried splitting it 
# using text_lis.split(".") so that I can count the sentences            
s = text_lis.split(".")
# the for average number of words per sentence 
char_len = 0
for line in s:
  words = line.split(" ")
     for word in words:
           char_len += len(word.split)
average_number_of words = char_len/len(words)
```

The actual output must be the average number of sentences and average number of words per sentence in that paragraph.The approach that I tried gave me the wrong the output because, there are certain words in the file which also use such punctuations like `.'` for ex Dr. etc and when I used `text_lis.split()` it also counts those words as the end of the sentence.

here is the sample text
I would love to try or hear the sample audio your app can produce. I do not want to purchase, because I've purchased so many apps that say they do something and do not deliver.

Can you please add audio samples with text you've converted? I'd love to see the end results.

Thanks!

THE AUTHOR.

Comment: It will help you can provide a sample input, and the output for that sample!

Comment: it is huge text file how can I input it and its out put is simply the average number of sentences and average number of words per sentence in that paragraph.

Comment: That is fine, but we don't need the full file, just paste a few paragraphs, expected output, and the output you get! Remember we cannot guess how your code performs until you provide us those information!

Comment: just tell me how you can calculate average words in a sentence

Comment: Let us help us help you, by providing the examples I have asked for, otherwise it is like executing your code in the dark, without knowing what input to run against! Does that make sense to you?

Comment: but where I can add that text

Comment: and also if you know how we can calculate average number of words per sentence that will be thankful to you

Comment: By https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55897177/edit the question, once you add the required input and output, I can help you further!

Comment: I have added few bits of paragraph in the edit section

Comment: That means you need to edit the question and save it, to update the question, also update the expected output as well!

Comment: there are the few lines

Comment: Got it, can you also add the expected output

Comment: expected output is nothing but there count simply

Comment: avg. of words per sentence = 32 and avg. no. of sentences = 20 these are raw values

Comment: You mean in this sentence ? `here is the sample text I would love to try or hear the sample audio your app can produce. I do not want to purchase, because I've purchased so many apps that say they do something and do not deliver.`

Comment: yes this is just a piece of text otherwise text is 6 mb

Comment: see if that works